RHEL7 Linux cannot find java path after installing java-11-openjdk
After installation of java-11-openjdk the Linux shell could not find the path to the java binary. Please see more details in the screenshot below.
We observed this issue on java-11 but we suspect the other versions will be the same.
Our Questions:
Where to check the installation paths of Java (not sure maybe also JDK, etc.), and how to add them to the system path?
Is there a way to let yum install add these paths.
We are new to the Java installation, so we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.
Screenshot:
[root@metabasev metabase]# yum install java-11-openjdk
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-11-openjdk.x86_64 1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-11-openjdk-headless(x86-64) = 1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9 for package: 1:java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjava.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjvm.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-11-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                            Arch             Version                         Repository                    Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 java-11-openjdk                    x86_64           1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9           rhel-7-server-rpms           244 k
Installing for dependencies:
 java-11-openjdk-headless           x86_64           1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9           rhel-7-server-rpms            39 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 39 M
Installed size: 165 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/2): java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64.rpm                                            | 244 kB  00:00:00
(2/2): java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64.rpm                                   |  39 MB  00:00:03
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                    11 MB/s |  39 MB  00:00:03
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : 1:java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64                                                1/2
failed to read link /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
  Installing : 1:java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64                                                         2/2
  Verifying  : 1:java-11-openjdk-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64                                                         1/2
  Verifying  : 1:java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64                                                2/2

Installed:
  java-11-openjdk.x86_64 1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9

Dependency Installed:
  java-11-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:11.0.23.0.9-2.el7_9

Complete!
[root@metabasev metabase]#
[root@metabasev metabase]#
[root@metabasev metabase]# which java
/usr/bin/which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)


We resolved the issue by following the link below:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_build_of_openjdk/11/html-single/installing_and_using_red_hat_build_of_openjdk_11_on_rhel/index
More specifically, we used the interactive command update-alternatives --config 'java'.
